# Как правильно записать данные из dataGridView в файл

Tags: c#, winforms

у меня проблема. Есть 2 формы, на первой заполняются данные о студенте, на второй находится datagridView с 10 столбцами, которые были созданы заранее. При заполнении всех данных они переносятся в класс с полями, которые принимают эти данные, после чего во второй форме идет обращение к ним, чтобы заполнить таблицу. Все работает исправно за исключением сохранения данных dataGridView в файл, поскольку после этой процедуры файл создается, но с пустым содержанием. Код сохранения прилагаю ниже.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        Stream MyStream;
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((MyStream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(MyStream);
                try
                {
                   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                        {
                            sw.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + " ");
                        }
                        sw.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                }
                finally
                {
                    sw.Close();
                }
                MyStream.Close();
            }
            
        }
    }
```

[image: Форма для ввода информации о человеке]
[image: Столбцы dataGridView]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, у вас уже есть `saveFileDialog1`, и вы его создали в дизайнере формы. Пусть он будет.

Можно конечно и свой создавать, но таким образом вы будете создавать каждый раз новый диалог, а в варинте с дизайнером - переиспользовать уже созданный. Это быстрее и экономнее по ресурсам.

Вот это вынесите в дизайнер формы

```csharp
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
```

[image: savefiledialog]

И попробуйте так

```csharp
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName)) 
        { 
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
                    {
                        sw.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
                        if (j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1) sw.Write(" "); // не пишем пробел после последней колонки
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если `StreamWriter` умеет открывать файл на запись по имени, вам незачем открывать дополнительный `Stream`.

Comment: Порой мне кажется, что с моей версией VS что-то не то, поскольку этот вариант мне тоже не помог. Сейчас попробую на другом устройстве, ибо это очень странно. Возможно, Вы помните проблему с тэгами radiobutton'ов, которую я когда-то тоже пытался решить, а все оказалось правильным. :)

Comment: @Defined123 Обновите код в вопросе на тот что сейчас и вам "не помог".

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл одну вещь, которую Вы указали в коде. Все работает, спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Defined123 отлично! А то я уже думал, что что-то со мной не так. Но я все равно сделал картинку, для потомков пригодится. :)

Comment: Прошу прощения, Вы тут?

Comment: Можно к Вам с вопросом обратиться?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109366/discussion-between-aepot-and-defined123).